# How to configure Istio EgressGateway with multiple hosts?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I’m working on setting up an Egress Gateway. I have a simple one that handles traffic for one host configured based on the Istio docs, so that part is fine. But when I look at how to handle multiple hosts, I find this verbiage:

> To direct multiple hosts through an egress gateway, you can include a
> list of hosts, or use * to match all, in the Gateway. The subset
> field in the DestinationRule should be reused for the additional
> hosts.

On [this Istio docs page](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/traffic-management/egress/egress-gateway/).

Unfortunately I have no idea what the second part of that actually means: "The subset field in the DestinationRule should be reused for the additional hosts." To be honest, I don't entirely understand how DR's work with EgressGateway's in general. I'm more used to a DR that specifies a set of pods as it's target in the "subset" field. So I don't quite get how the DR connections a specific host to the Gateway.  I tried the following, but this doesn't work:

egress-gateway.yml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: istio-egressgateway
  namespace: env-specific-egress-experiments
spec:
  selector:
    istio: egressgateway
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
     - news.ycombinator.com
     - www.slashdot.org
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: env-specific-egressgateway-dr
  namespace: env-specific-egress-experiments
spec:
  host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
  subsets:
  - name: hn
  - name: slashdot
```

service-entries.yml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: news-ycombinator-com
  namespace: env-specific-egress-experiments
spec:
  hosts:
  - news.ycombinator.com
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http-port-hn
    protocol: HTTP
  - number: 443
    name: https-port-hn
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS

---

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: www-slashdot-org
  namespace: env-specific-egress-experiments
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.slashdot.org
  ports:
  - number: 80
    name: http-port-slashdot
    protocol: HTTP
  - number: 443
    name: https-port-slashdot
    protocol: HTTPS
  resolution: DNS
```

virtual-service.yml

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: external-service-vs-hn
  namespace: env-specific-egress-experiments
spec:
  hosts:
  - news.ycombinator.com
  gateways:
   - istio-egressgateway
   - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
    - port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
       host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
       subset: hn
       port:
         number: 80
    rewrite:
      authority: news.ycombinator.com
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway
      port: 80        
    route:
    - destination:
        host: news.ycombinator.com
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
    rewrite:
      authority: news.ycombinator.com
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: external-service-vs-slash
  namespace: env-specific-egress-experiments
spec:
  hosts:
  - www.slashdot.org
  gateways:
   - istio-egressgateway
   - mesh
  http:
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - mesh
    - port: 80
    route:
    - destination:
       host: istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local
       subset: slashdot
       port:
         number: 80
    rewrite:
      authority: www.slashdot.org
  - match:
    - gateways:
      - istio-egressgateway
      port: 80        
    route:
    - destination:
        host: www.slashdot.org
        port:
          number: 80
      weight: 100
    rewrite:
      authority: www.slashdot.org
```

If I try to curl one of the hosts with this configuration, I get

```
/ # curl http://news.ycombinator.com
/ # curl -SsL -D - http://news.ycombinator.com
HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
date: Tue, 23 Feb 2021 19:27:49 GMT
server: envoy
x-envoy-upstream-service-time: 45
content-length: 0
```

Also, just as an FYI, a few additional points:

1. This is just a simulation of part of what I'm trying to accomplish. Obviously I don't really care about connecting to HN or /. Those are just stand-ins for external sites in general
2. Long-term, the goal is to put an abstract name in front of a external service that can vary in terms of the actual host, based on the deployment. Eg, if I deploy qa-deployment.yml, then "mongodatabase" actually points to mongo.qa.mycompany.com, and if I deploy int-deployment.yml, "mongodatabase" points to mongo.int.mycompany.com, and so on. I think I can accomplish this part with an ExternalName service, and/or a ClusterIP that "floats" and doesn't point to any pods, but is just there for DNS resolution so the VirtualService can trigger.
3. Ultimately I want all outgoing traffic to go through an EgressGateway. But there will be multiple "things" that need to go through it, hence the particular point I'm stuck on now, which is getting the EgressGateway to work with multiple hosts.

Comment: What is your istio version? Also, does the `curl www.slashdot.org` also return 503?

Comment: Istio version 1.6.4. And yes, curling either endpoint returns the same error.

Comment: Did you solve this?

Comment: Yes, got it all working. I meant to come back and post a self-answer to help anybody else who runs into any of this, but just haven't had time yet.

Comment: I think the error here is that you are your egress in the as destination in the virtual services, istio-egressgateway.istio-system.svc.cluster.local

Comment: @mindcrime would you mind self-answering this issue? Running into it now. Trying to add multiple matchers to virtual service that would represent routes (/books, /videos), but exploring breaking each route into its own VS

Comment: That was so long ago I'm not sure I remember what the problem was now. But I'll try to see if I can find any of my old notes and post something if I can.